# Error when i execute syncdb

Tags: django, django-models

I am facing an error while executing `python manage.py suncdb`

the error is

```
C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py:75: DeprecationWarning: Th
e ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX setting has been removed; use STATIC_URL instead.
  "use STATIC_URL instead.", DeprecationWarning)
C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\localflavor\ca\ca_provinces.py:14:
RuntimeWarning: There have been recent changes to the CA localflavor. See the re
lease notes for details
  RuntimeWarning
Creating tables ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
442, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line
379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 191,
 in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 220,
 in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 351,
 in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\syncdb.py"
, line 109, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 189,
in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive, db=db)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 172,
in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\management.py"
, line 47, in update_contenttypes
    content_type_display = '\n'.join(['    %s | %s' % (ct.app_label, ct.model) f
or ct in content_types])
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'app_label'
```

and i tried to convert DB and all tables and fields collation to `utf8_general_ci` but nothing changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says you've got a string instead of Model Meta options. It's not related to collation probably.

What change have you made before the error appeared?

Comment: Thanks raacer, I'm just migrating the site, got a recent db backup and the files, to the local, but it gives me this error.

Comment: What django version do you use, and what version you used before? It seems you have python 2.5, does it correspond to the original python version that you migrate from?

Comment: If you not sure, I suggest to upgrade your python to some recent 2.x version and see if the error still appears.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, I just dropped the database and re-ran syncdb and it was fine.